# Check action noroute (404) on phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, 404

Is there a way to check if the current page is a 404 page (action = noroute) in a phtml file?

We have some javascript code to handle redirections based on certain cookies, and this is causing a redirection loop.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 404 page is rendered by Mage_Cms_IndexController::noRouteAction() in a vanilla Magento installation, so you could try something like this:

```
$action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName()
if($action == 'noRoute'){
   //do some stuff
}
```

also follow link for backend:

http://inchoo.net/magento/enhance-magento-404-page/

**I hope this will help you.**